# xcode 12 build not displaying images

Tags: react-native

I am developing a reat-native application
with following versions :
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",

The build doesn't shows images.
I foud following solution :

In pod file made following changes :

```
pre_install do |installer|
    puts("Image fix for ios14: remove this when upgradeing to >= 0.63.3")
    find = "_currentFrame.CGImage;"
    replace = "_currentFrame.CGImage ;} else { [super displayLayer:layer];"
    op = `sed -ie "s/#{find}/#{replace}/" 
    ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m`
    puts("Image fix for ios14 done")
end
```

Then tried to build but still it is not working

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279

use react-native+0.63.0.patch or upgrade react-native version

Answer (score 0):

You need to display images if **_currentFrame is nil**. The solution is to add an else block to execute **[super displayLayer:layer]**;

Simple add these changes in your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  ## Fix for images
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m", "_currentFrame.CGImage;", "_currentFrame.CGImage ;} else { [super displayLayer:layer];")
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
    text = File.read(name)
    replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
    if text != replace
      puts "Fix: " + name
      File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
      STDOUT.flush
    end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

It will find for the specific text in the specific file and add an else block. Do **pod install** again.